# Apache exit signal Segmentation fault (11) while doing POST with more than 85 fields

Tags: php, apache, post, https, segmentation-fault

I had lot of **exit signal Segmentation fault (11)** errors in the apache log file.

After a few hours of disabling things and doing some tests I found that this happens only when I've a HTML form with more than 85 fields doing a POST over HTTPS, I mean.. if I try to do the POST with 84 fields, it works but if I try with 86 I have an error in the browser and the segmentation fault in the log file.

I tried to disable the firewall, change PHP settings and nothing works (is not related to the maximum of post fields in the php.ini), but when I tried to do that over HTTP it works fine.

I'm doing this in a simple HTML file so I think is not an issue related to PHP.

Any ideas? Suggestion? Thanks!

**Apache Version**

*Server version: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix)*

*Server built:   May 10 2019 11:45:46*

**OS**

*Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)*

*CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7*

*Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64*

*Architecture: x86-64*

Comment: Please add : Apache version (`httpd -V), OS version